# How to simplify the maths to determine the mutual inductance between two multi-layer rectangular coils of arbitrary dimensions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, inductance

I am experimenting with wireless power transfer. The maths to directly determine mutual inductance between two multi-layer rectangular coils of arbitrary area, separated by an arbitrary distance, angle and ratio of turns is very complex mathematically.

Is there a mathematical simplification, i.e. a canonical formula that can be used for this calculation?

Comment: Please show your effort and your thinking on it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no simple formula for this. You can either do a double integral to determine how the flux generated by one coil interacts with the other. Or you can do a numerical analysis using finite elements or other methods.

Or, practically, you can simply build a prototype system and measure the effect.